# Migration to M2

Tags: magento2

I have an old Magento 1.9 website that I want to migrate to M2.

I also have a M2 store which is fully developed now.

Both websites have different products, design, configuration.

So my question is:

- would it be better to create a new store under my M2 installation to migrate the M 1.9 ?
- or is it best to have a complete new installation where I migrate the M 1.9 ?

If the 1st solution is the best (new store under actual M2 installation), would each website have a dedicated cache ? Or share the same one ?

I would like to avoid to flush both store caches, if I flush only 1.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

it actually depends on which are the business requirements, but if you don't have any constraints, i would suggest you create a new install dedicated to the migrated data.

and to answer your second question, the cache is shared in a multi-website configuration under same Magento instance. so one more reason to create a dedicated website on a new Magento instance (again, if you don't have any constraints like: business requirements saying you have to use the same instance, budget in allocating separate resources, etc).